# beta distribution fit to normalized entropy term -$p \ln{p}$

Tags: probability-distributions, entropy

Given that entropy term $-p \ln{p}$ has support (0,1) and beta distribution has same support, was interested in understanding if Beta $( x|\alpha, \beta )$ might exactly fit to normalized pdf $f(x)=A x \ln{x}$ ... using numerical methods (see graph below) it appears that it comes close for values $\alpha = 1.6267$ and $\beta = 2.0769$[image: beta distribution fit to normalized x lnx]

How would you approach deriving analytical values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which mostly closely match Beta distribution to $-x \ln{x}$?

Also, is there a notational shortcut for representing/discussing entropy term $-x \ln{x}$

The beta distribution has pdf $f(x; \alpha , \beta )=\frac{\Gamma (\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma (\alpha)\Gamma (\beta)}x^{\alpha - 1} (1-x)^{\beta -1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach I have seen many times when attempting to approximate an arbitrary pdf by a beta pdf is the *moment matching approach*. Let $\mu$ and  $\sigma^2$ denote the mean and variance of the arbitrary pdf, respectively. Noting that the mean and variance of the beta pdf equals $\alpha/(\alpha +\beta)$ and $\alpha \beta / ((\alpha +\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1))$, respectively, one only has to solve the system 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\alpha}{\alpha +\beta}&=\mu,\\
\frac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha +\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}&=\sigma^2,
\end{align}
$$
with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

For the pdf $-4 x \log(x)$, it holds $\mu=1/4$ and $\sigma^2=17/324$. Solving the system results in 
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &= 28/17 \approx 1.64706,\\
\beta &= 35/17 \approx 2.05882,
\end{align}
$$
which are actually quite close to the values you identified numerically.

[image]

Comment: thank you ... very much appreciated @Stelios!

Comment: @phdmba7of12 you are welcome!

Comment: and thus we almost have a rather untidy approximation formula for ln x involving powers of seventeenth root of x

Comment: is there a source that gives the steps in-between for doing "with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$"?